# El boton en HTML no ejecuta la función de .gs

Tags: html, botón, google-apps-script

Tengo una función que arma un cuadro de dialogo "`function EEA()`" (en formato HTML, nombre "`HTMLCuadroDialogo`" )en una hoja de calculo para ingresar dos valores (año y mes) , una vez completados los valores debe ejecutarse una función "function Alumno(mes)"que está en el codigo .gs. (debe traer el valor `mes=año+mes` del   HTML.
El boton que no funciona es el boton que ejecuta la función `Alumnos`, la función `alumnos` funciona porque la pruebo por separado y funciona correctamente. Solo falta que cuando haga click en el botón tome los valores de del cuadro de dialogo y lo utilice para ejecutar la función `alumnos()`.
No logro que la función se ejecute.-

Código .gs

```js
function EEA() {
  // Ingreso de Año y Mes a enviar email
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("HTMLCuadroDialogo");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'My add-on');
}
```

```js
function Alumnos(mes) {
  var sps = SpreadsheetApp.openById("idspreadsheet");
  var hoja = sps.getSheetByName("name");
  var valores = hoja.getDataRange().getValues().filter(row => row[23] == mes);
  var asunto = "blablablabla" + mes;
  for (i in valores) {
    var fila = valores[i];
    var alumno1 = fila[7]; // Datos Alumnos
    var tutor = fila[16]; // tutor

    // preparación de Cuerpo del email en el archivo cuerpoHTML.html
    var cuerpo = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('cuerpoAlumnosHTML'); //
    cuerpo.nombrealumno1 = alumno1;


    var plantilla = cuerpo.evaluate().getContent();


    // Envio de email

    GmailApp.createDraft(mail, asunto, "", {
      htmlBody: plantilla,
      cc: ccmail
    });
    var i = 1 + +i
  }
}
```

HTML - HTMLCuadroDialogo.HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  Año
  <select id="fanio">
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
    <option value="2022">2022</option>
    <option value="2023">2023</option>
  </select>
  Mes
  <select id="fmes">
    <option value="Enero">Enero</option>
    <option value="Febrero">Febrero</option>
    <option value="Marzo">Marzo</option>
    <option value="Diciembre">Diciembre</option>
  </select>
  <button onmouseup="closeDia()">Close</button>
  <p>
    <button id="button1" type="button">Aceptar</button>
  </p>

  <script>
    window.closeDia = function() {
      google.script.host.close();
    };
    // Step 1: Find the element we want the event on
    var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");

    // Step 2: Define the event listener function
    var onButtonClick = function() {
      var anio = document.getElementById("fanio").value;
      var mesi = document.getElementById("fmes").value;
      var mes;

      mes = anio + " - " + fmes;

      google.script.run.Alumnos(mes);

    };

    // Step 3: Attach event listener to element
    button1.addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. ¿Qué ocurre cuando pulsas el botón? ¿Revisaste las ejecuciones (pulsando en el cuarto icono del panel izquierdo de Google Apps Script, si tienes activada la nueva interfaz)? Revisa ese apartado y verifica el estado del código, allí te dirá si se ejecutó con éxito o no o si hubo errores y cuáles fueron esos errores.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Como indica A. Cedano la pregunta es poco clara pero además falta que indiques si se ha registrado un mensaje de error en la consola de las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador o en la página de ejecuciones del script.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuestas. Veré si puedo aclarar la pregunto ya que es la primera vez que realizo una.
Tengo una app script que habre un cuadro de dialogo en mi sheet (EAA()). En el cuadro de dialogo selecciono "año" y "mes" y este valor combinado deber usarse para ejecutarse la función (Alumno(mes)). Si pruebo la función Alumno(mes), incorporando la variable directamente, la función funciona correctamente.
Cuando trato de que esa función se ejecute desde el botón "ACEPTAR" del cuadro de dialogo, no sucede nada.
Me fijé como me indicaste en "registro de ejecuciones" y no indica error alguno

Answer (score 0):

Hay un error en las siguiente línea del código del archivo HTML - HTMLCuadroDialogo.HTML

```
mes = anio + " - " + fmes;
```

El error es que `fmes` es `undefined` ya que no se ha declarado. Quizás la corrección sea cambiar dicha variable por `mesi` la cual ha sido declarada una líneas antes.