# Evento onclick no llama a función

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, onclick, funcion

Tengo un problema en html cuando programo en Google Apps Scripts, el evento onclick no llama a la función `PintarParrafos()`, por lo que mi boton se queda sin funcionar en mi formulario de Docs drive, adjunto código y foto más abajo, que solucion me recomiendan??

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

    <label>Introduce la cantidad de párrafos a introducir</label>
    <input type="number" id="cantidad"><br>

    <label>Introduce el parrafo</label>
    <input type="text" id="frase"><br>


    <button type="button" onclick="PintarParrafos()">Pintar párrafos</button>

  <script>

    function PintarParrafos() {

      var texto = document.getElementByid("frase").value;
      var cantidad = document.getElementByid("cantidad").value;

      google.script.run.CrearParrafosV4(texto,cantidad);
      google.script.host.close();

    }



  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Te aparece algún error en la consola del navegador?

Comment: Ningun error... nose que puede ser... lo tengo literalmente igual que la persona que hizo el codigo pero a el si le funciona... nose porque a mi no

Comment: Además de lo que mencioné en mi respuesta en el código de tu proyecto podría haber una etiqueta html puesta incorrectamente, error de mayúsculas/minúsculas, entre otras cosas. Edita la pregunta para agregar un [mcve], esto implica incluir una función que abra el diálogo y la que sería llamada del lado del servidor, los logs de ejecución, y los logs de la consola del navegador.

Comment: No entendí muy bien lo que dijiste, soy ignorante en el tema, pero edite la imagen poniendo errores que me aparecen en la consola del navegador nose si sirva.. también aparece otro error en rojo de excepted number

Comment: Por etiquetas me refiero `<body></body>` `<input>` `<button></button>`, podría ser que en Google Apps Script tengas un error que no se ha visto aquí. Google Apps Script / JavaScript son sensibles a mayúsculas y minúsculas, por ejemplo, en el código se muestra `CrearParrafosV4` pero si la función en el archivo .gs se llama `crearParrafosV4` no la va a encontrar. Sobre los mensajes de error generalmente es mejor agregarlos como texto en lugar de imagen. Agregar ese otro error, así como el código del archivo .gs.

Comment: La función de `document` se llama `getElementById`, con la `i` mayúscula. De hecho, al hacer un despliegue de eso en GAS, sí que sale en la consola del navegador

Comment: Eso era!!! era un error de minuscula y mayusculas como decia Rubén, gracias Alfabravo por encontrar el error, ahora me funciona perfecto!!

Answer (score 2):

`google.script.run` es asíncrono así que es muy probable `google.script.host.close()` se esté ejecutando antes de que la función `CrearParrafosV4` sea ejectutada.

Una solución simple sería reemplazar

```
 google.script.run.CrearParrafosV4(texto,cantidad);
 google.script.host.close();
```

por

```
 google.script.run
 .withSuccessHandler( () => google.script.host.close())
 .CrearParrafosV4(texto,cantidad);
```

Relacionado

- [Crear un botón que onClick envíe un email](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/429999/65)
- [El boton en HTML no ejecuta la función de .gs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/441853/65)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero no me funciono man... el boton del formulario sigue sin funcionar... es como si el evento onclick no llamara a ninguna funcion